# Application of Cauchy's first limit theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Cauchy’s first theorem on limits:**    If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to l, then the sequence $\{y_n\}$ also converges to l, where $y_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}$.

Prove that $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}{2n+1}=0$.

Proceed:
Let  $u_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} u_n=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_1+u_2+\dots+u_n}{n}=0$, i.e., $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}{n}=0$. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Μultiply your limit by $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n}{2n+1}=1/2.$ Then, by the properties of limits you get that the desired limit is equal to $1/2 \times 0=0.$